# Как пользоваться рекурсией?

Tags: рекурсия, c++

Не могу понять рекурсию. Как написать терминальное выражение, как может функция вызвать саму   себя? Нужно написать программу на С++ с помощью рекурсии.

Comment: Чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно понять рекурсию. Это же очевидно, насколько, это очевидно.

Просто написать программу с помощью рекурсии не выйдет (хотя можно и подумать), возможно, Вам просто нужно программу с рекурсией написать?

Comment: Примеров использования рекурсии может быть множество.
Самый распространенный из них - вычисление факториала, когда каждый шаг выполнения одной и той же функции зависит от результата выполнения предыдущего.

Comment: Для начала примите за правило, что все данные, которыми оперирует рекурсивная функция (кроме нужных только для промежуточных вычислений в одном ее вызове) передаются в аргументах функции.

Пока не пользуйтесь никакими внешними (extern/static, данные класса, если функция это метод класса) по отношению к ней данными при разработке алгоритма.

Потом, когда освоитесь, сами поймете как и когда в рекурсивной функции можно оперировать нелокальными переменными.

Comment: Да, программу с рекурсией, замена умножения сложением единиц, то есть нужно плюсануть единицу столько раз, сколько потребуется для ответа. Допустим, 2*3 значит, 1+1+1+1+1+1=6 только рекурсивно, без цикла while или for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как может функция вызвать саму себя?

В ее теле должен быть вызов самой себя. Естественно, этот вызов должен осуществляться по условию, иначе программа уйдет в нечто, похожее на бесконечный цикл, только хуже, чем бесконечный цикл.

Мне очень нравится пример из SICP, который позволяет найти квадратный корень методом Ньютона.
Представим, что некоторая функция Х принимает на вход число, от которого нужно найти квадратный корень, и число, которое мы предполагаем близким к этому корню, а в ответ функция возвращает число, которое гарантированно находится ближе к квадратному корню, нежели наше предположение. В таком случае мы будем вызывать эту функцию следующим образом:

```
найти_квадратный_корень(число, предположение, погрешность)
{
    предположение = Х(число, предположение)
    если модуль(число - (предположение в квадрате)) меньше погрешности
        вернуть предположение
    иначе
        вернуть найти_квадратный_корень(число, предположение, погрешность)
}
```

таким образом функция вызывает сама себя, пока предположение не удовлетворит заданной погрешности.

Comment: Я буду писать программу для замены умножения сложением единиц, то есть нужно плюсануть единицу столько раз, сколько потребуется для ответа. Допустим 2*3 значит, 1+1+1+1+1+1=6 только рекурсивно, без цикла while или for. 
 
То есть я так понял что моем случае должна вызваться функция i++(добавление единицы, сколько потребуется для верного ответа).

Comment: @Sergos, нет, в умножении вообще не существует никаких "плюс один". Умножение a \* b может рассматриваться как сумма из b слагаемых, каждое из которых равно a:

    a * b = E(i = 1; i = b){a} = a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + ... + a[b]

В таком случае рекурсивная функция будет иметь два аргумента: умножаемое число и множитель. Если множитель равен 1, то функция возвращает само число, если множитель больше единицы, то функция возвращает результат вызова самой себя для множителя на единицу меньше:

Comment:     function multiply(a, b) {
        if (b == 1) {
            return a;
        }
        return a + multiply(a, b - 1);
    }

(полная версия будет чуть длинней, конечно, плюс сейчас еще вспомнят переполнение):

    function multiply(a, b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (b == 1) {
            return a;
        }
        if (b < 0) {
            return -multiply(a, -b);
        }
        return a + multiply(a, b - 1);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Отлично написано:

http://cppstudio.com/post/418/

Answer (score 1):

Несколько просветляющих примеров рекурсии.

```
int sum_digits(const int n)
{
    return n < 10 ? n : n % 10 + sum_digits(n / 10);
}

void rev(void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (c != EOF)
    {
        rev();
        putchar(c);
    }
}

int gcd(const int a, const int b)
{
    return a == 0 ? b : gcd(b, a % b);
}

int max3(const int a, const int b, const int c)
{
    if (a > b) { return max3(b, a, c); }
    if (b > c) { return max3(a, c, b); }
    return c;
}

int power(const int x, const int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```